# Call Method of Generic Class within an Object[] Array

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I have a generic class, called `Node<E>` and I'm trying to define a static method that will return an array of objects of this type.  I understand that Java does not allow the creation of generic type arrays within a class so we have to create an Object array and pass our generic types through the object.

For an example of the code, let's define it as:

```
public static Object[] returnArray() {
    Object[] output;
    //code which adds Node<E> to output
    return output;
```

When I implement this code though, I am not able to:

- perform this class's methods on the objects within the array as they are of type `Object`

  - If `Node<E>` had a method `.getVal()` the following code results in an error:

    - `Object[] nodes = Node.returnArray(head);
      nodes[0].getVal();`
- cast and return method array to a  `Node<E>[]` array, even when explicit of the type.

  - `Node<Integer>[] nodes = (Node<Integer>[]) Node.returnArray(head);`

So the only way I am currently accessing the methods of each node is by assigning them to a variable by casting:

```
Object[] nodes = Node.returnArray(head);
Node<Integer> returned1 = (Node<Integer>) nodes[0];
Node<Integer> returned2 = (Node<Integer>) nodes[1];
```

But you can see how redundant it gets as the code grows.  Is there a better way to access generic objects passed to an array?

Comment: You can't make an array of `E`, or of `Node<E>`, but you can certainly make an array of `Node`.

Comment: Also, you should probably just make a List instead. No point dealing with the headaches of trying to get generics and arrays to work together if you can just use a List.

Comment: you can create an array of `Node` and cast it to `Node<E>[]`, and add warning suppression to your method. sure it's now your disposal to make sure it's indeed `E`(which in many cases wouldn't be hard).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You **can** create generic arrays. You just need the `Class` object for that. Consider this overly complicated program for printing the number 6:

```
public class GenericClass<T> {

    T[] array;

    public GenericClass(int length, Class<T> clazz) {
        array = (T[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(clazz, length);
    }

    public T get(int i) {
        return array[i];
    }

    public T set(int i, T val) {
        return array[i] = val;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        GenericClass<Integer> example = new GenericClass<>(5, Integer.class);
        example.set(0, 6);
        System.out.println(example.get(0)); //Prints 6
    }
}
```

This way, the array you create is **really** of type `T[]`, not `Object[]`, so it's safe to use and even externalize. 
Another option, of course, is just to use a list.

Comment: That's not relevant here. They are not trying to create an array of a type variable type. The runtime component type of the array here *is* known at compile time -- it is `Node`.